# Fixed quanitifer for regex with comma separated words

Tags: regex, quantifiers

I have this regex for multiple words separated by comma:
`\w+(,\w+)*`
The amount of words should be limited to exactly **four**, I tried the following but this didn't do the job: `\w{1}(,\w+){3}`

Example of *valid* input:
`12, en_US, default, mobile`

Example of *invalid* input:
`23, en_US`

Comment: There are spaces in your input - but your regex doesn't handle them. You probably need anchors too (depends on the language/method you use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex: `\w{1}(,\w+){3}`, the first word is limited to one character, I guess you want:

```
^\w+(,\s*\w+){3}$
```

where I've added anchors to match the whole line and optional spaces before the words.